# JSP dynamic table with one input box and one checkbox in each row

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp

I am now designing .jsp that contains a dynamic table which the data will be retrieved from datasource (which doesn't matter). The requirement is same with my topic. And I have complete part of my code but failed to get the user input value.

My code is as below:

```
<form id="select" method="post" action="select">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Plan List</h2>
<p style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <button type="submit"
        >Select</button>
</p>
<table class="details">
    <tr class="details">
        <th class="details" style="text-align: center;">Plan Name</th>
        <th class="details" style="text-align: center;">Quota</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="plan">
        <tr class="details">
            <td class="details" style="text-align: center;">${plan.planName}</td>
            <td class="details" style="text-align: center;"><input
                type="text" name="quota2" min="1"></td>
            <td class="details"><input type="checkbox" name="selection2"
                value="${selectedPartnerId},${plan.planId}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

The design is to select the rows by clicking the checkboxs, then click the select button to submit the selected rows. I am now able to pass the data by putting the variable to value. However, I cannot find any way to pass the value that belonged to user's input. I have already spent two days for this. Please give me some advice. Thanks a lot for your precious time....

More details for your information...
I am now using java as backend and get the selected checkboxs results lists by "request.getParameterValues("selection2")"...

Comment: How are you retrieving input value in backend?

Comment: I used request.getParameterValues("selection2") and return as String[] with my selected rows, thanks for your comment

Comment: request.getParameterValues("selection2") will retrive checkbox values. What about  for <input  type="text" name="quota2" min="1"> ? You want to fetch quota2 values?

Comment: yes.. I can fetch the quota2 results. But what the requirement want is to get the information from the selected rows only. If I input quota2 without ticking the checkbox, I can still fetch the result which I don't need and I cannot tell if the value is from which row too. One checkbox and one input field for one record and there will be multiple rows in the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself by using the same fetching methods. However, I will pass the index number of the table in order to get the corresponding value of quota (which is the user input).